# Progress bar with bootstrap, ajax laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, progress-bar

I´m trying to create a progress bar while uploading files and importing data in database.

I have created an importer with laravel and ajax with jquery. In this importer I´m reading all data from a CSV file. I´m getting all rows and cols from this file and while I´m reading this file, I´m doing a insert query with eloquent. This is my code:

```
$fp = fopen($route, 'r');

        // header
        $head = fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ';', '"');
        $header = [];
        
        $header[0] = 'nomape';
        $header[1] = 'direccion';
        $header[2] = 'cp';
        $header[3] = 'ciudad';
        $header[4] = 'provincia';
        $header[5] = 'telefono';
        $header[6] = 'movil';

        $rows = 0;
        $cells = 0;
        
        // Rows
        while($column = fgetcsv($fp, 8192, ';', '"'))
        {
            // build array to can combine header and this array
            $columns = [];
            
            foreach ($column as $val) {
                array_push($columns, $this->delete_accent($val));
            }

            $column = array_combine($header, $columns);
            $result = Listado::insert($column);
            
            if($result){
                $rows++;
            }
            
            $cells++;
        }
        
        fclose($fp);
        return 'Importados un total de: ' .$rows. ' de un total de: ' . $cells;
```

These operations take time. In my web `browser console` in `network tab`, I can show my http petition in pending while importing all my data. My CSV has a 69000 register.

[image]

With this code I´m building my progress bar:

```
$.ajax({    
                    xhr: function() {
                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                                // Place upload progress bar visibility code here
                                console.log(percentComplete);
                            }
                        }, false);
                        return xhr;
                    },
```

But this returns 100% value in seconds, when these operations take many minutes. My question is how can I get real progress to create my progress bar ?

Comment: check this: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-laravel-file-upload-with-progress-bar-exampleexample.html

Comment: @MartinOsusky thanks for your response, but i haven´t got form, i´m sending my file with event change my input file

Comment: @MartinOsusky that is a progress bar for the upload not for the file processing. it will show 100% before processing the first row server side.

Comment: ok, now I understand your goal.. this could help you: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/realtime-progress-bar

Comment: @MartinOsusky installing laravel echo and messing with websocket just for one upload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your approach and do the csv traitement in 2 steps while repeating the second steps till the end of file.

**First step**
With ajax, do a normal upload without processing the data. the request should return the uploaded file identifier with the row counts.

**Second step**
With ajax, call for the first 100 rows to be processed (change the 100 value to your liking)

Once the request responds, update the progress bar (since you have the total count of the rows (100/69000 alias 0.1%) and call for the next 100 entries to be processed.

repeat this till you reach the row count. At the last process, you can delete the file.

PS: you will need some way to clean up trash uploads (those wich their process has not reached 100%) You can do that by cleaverly naming the uploaded file. For example, add the date of upload (plus unique id) to the file name and delete anything older than 24h.

Comment: thanks for your response, i don´t understand very well that you say me. i´m uploading my file with ajax ok, but how i say that process this file? in my code php i´m getting all row and cols but i don´t understand... it´s my first time with progress bar

Comment: @scorpions78 first request, dont loop the rows of the files. just return something to identify the file and the row count. once you get those results in Javascript, you do another ajax call with the id of the file and skip=0, count=100. Now in the controller get the file (with the id) and loop the first 100 entries.

Comment: @scorpions78 join me in the chat to discuss it more https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236076/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-68813739-progress-bar-with-bootstrap-ajax-lar

Answer (score 0):

For uploading you can use client side to notify of progress (if you're using ajax).

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total  * 100 >>>0;
        // Do something with download progress
        console.log("upload" + percentComplete + "%")

    }
}, false);
```

For importing and server processing progress you can use A. WebSockets server or B. an API service provider (such as rejax.io) for this. Then whenever a progress is made in server you make a call to API and client(s) will receive.

```
// if using PHP for example.
Rejax::send($str_channel_name, $str_message);
```

Proper discloser: I run https://rejax.io service